# Доступ к элементам, сконвертированным из xml в json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Делаю запрос к API [сюда](http://api.travelpayouts.com/v2/prices/special-offers), в ответ получаю xml-строку, затем на стороне сервера(PHP) конвертирую строку в json. После чего, могу обращаться за этой json-строкой при помощи ajax-запроса, что я и попытался сделать, но получил вот такую строку:

```
{  
    "offer":{  
        "@attributes":{  
            "airline":"Россия",
            "airline_code":"FV",
            "title":"Из Санкт-Петербурга в Ростов-на-Дону от 5000 рублей! Специальное предложение от авиакомпании Россия",
            "id":"21888",
            "href":"https://www.aviasales.ru/offers/iz-sankt-peterburga-v-rostov-na-donu-ot-5000-rublei-spetsialnoe-predlozhenie-ot-aviakompanii-rossiya",
            "sale_date_begin":"1475625600",
            "sale_date_end":"1512086400",
            "flight_date_begin":"1475625600",
            "flight_date_end":"1490400000",
            "link":"https://hydra.aviasales.ru/adaptors/special_offer?iata=FV&utm_source=www&lo…Fnews%2Fsale_of_tickets_for_flights_from_st_petersburg_to_rostov_on_don%2F"
        },
        "description":{  

        },
        "conditions":"<ul><li>Цены на авиабилеты указаны с учетом топливных, аэропортовых и государственных сборов.</li><li>Количество авиабилетов на каждом рейсе по данному тарифу ограничено.</li><li>Полные условия продажи авиабилетов на сайте авиакомпании.</li></ul>",
        "route":[  
            {  
                "@attributes":{  
                    "from_iata":"LED",
                    "to_iata":"ROV",
                    "from_name":"Санкт-Петербург",
                    "to_name":"Ростов-на-Дону",
                    "class":"эконом",
                    "oneway_price":"от 5000 рублей",
                    "roundtrip_price":""
                }
            },
            {  
                "@attributes":{  
                    "from_iata":"LED",
                    "to_iata":"ROV",
                    "from_name":"Санкт-Петербург",
                    "to_name":"Ростов-на-Дону",
                    "class":"эконом",
                    "oneway_price":"",
                    "roundtrip_price":"от 10000 рублей"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Таких `offer` может быть несколько, но вопрос в том, как мне обращаться к полям с именем `@attributes`? К слову, вывод обрабатываю при помощи **for in**.

Comment: Нельзя, что бы `offer` было несколько. Почему вы не можете обращаться к xml файлу?

Comment: @Yuri jQuery умеет работать с xml и выводить из него конкретно то, что мне нужно?

Comment: Чем вам не нравится такое обращение `obj.offer['@attributes'].airline`

Comment: а в чем проблема с `for..in` ? непонятно...... `for (var test in json.offer) {
console.log(json.offer[test]);
}`  спокойно работает.........а у jquery есть https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: @Orange_shadow я пользуюсь tampermonkey для проверки кода на ошибки. Так вот, он ругается на то, что я не использую dot notation. По этому, стараюсь работать только и только с dot notation.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Ну тогда переменные называй валидно, `@attributes` - это явно не валидное название